# Drush was not able to start the Drupal database

Tags: drupal, mamp, drush

When I start drush en name_of_module in terminal i get this error

Im using mamp and 5.3.27 php version

Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.34
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database username      :  root
 Database name          :  ceo
 Default theme          :  garland
 Administration theme   :  garland
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin
 Drush version          :  6.5.0
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /Users/edinpuzic/Desktop/Projekti/CEO/cm 
                           s
 Site path              :  sites/default
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files

Comment: Are you in the same folder as your settings.php file when you run this?

Comment: I'm in root folder of drupal site.

My settings.php looks like this:

$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'ceo',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);

Comment: You need to execute your drush command from your folder with the settings.php file

Comment: I try, same error :(

Comment: You do not need to be in the folder where settings.php is located. You need to specifiy the website url.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the answer to another/similar question I answered recently. drush says in your snippet above, that it asumes the site URI `http://default`. I'm sure that's not correct? Drush needs some context to know where to get your installation (install folder and database). It knows the installation root, but not the URL (to select the correct sites/folder/).

You might want to use the option `--root`to specify the webroot of your drupal installation. You can also specify the website URL using the option `--uri`, if you have a multisite installation. Look at http://docs.drush.org/en/master/usage/#options for an in-depth description.

But the best way to handle you setup is drush aliases (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/usage/#site-aliases). You define an alias `@site1` etc. and this alias references the webroot and site URL (and optionally other parameters as well).